# delete Task / PeriodicTask in celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

How can I delete a regular Task or PeriodicTask in celery?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You `revoke` the task: See [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html#celery.app.control.Control.revoke):

```
Control.revoke(task_id, destination=None, terminate=False, signal='SIGTERM', **kwargs)
    Tell all (or specific) workers to revoke a task by id.

    If a task is revoked, the workers will ignore the task and not execute it after all.

    Parameters: 
        task_id – Id of the task to revoke.
        terminate – Also terminate the process currently working on the task (if any).
        signal – Name of signal to send to process if terminate. Default is TERM.
```

Comment: and how can i get all task list?