# how to remove task from celery with redis broker?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, celeryd

I Have add some wrong `task` to a `celery` with redis `broker`

but now I want to remove the incorrect `task` and I can't find any way to do this

Is there some commands or some api to do this ?

Comment: See if it'll help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557424/delete-task-periodictask-in-celery

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I know two ways of doing so:

1) Delete queue directly from broker. In your case it's Redis. There are two commands that could help you: **llen** (to find right queue) and **del** (to delete it).

2) Start celery worker with **--purge** or **--discard** options. Here is help:

```
--purge, --discard    Purges all waiting tasks before the daemon is started.
                      **WARNING**: This is unrecoverable, and the tasks will
                      be deleted from the messaging server.
```

Comment: thanks for replay, celery is too complex,i have change my project to python-rq

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Reddis has still all the queue and I can't delete it. Celery continues recieving tasks

Comment: In case this doesn't clean up all of your celery issues, I also encourage you to check for zombie process using `ps` and run `kill` on them.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Why was it accepted?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use the `celery control revoke [id1 [id2 [... [idN]]]]` (do not forget to pass the `-A project.application` flag too). Where id1 to idN are task IDs. However, it is not guaranteed to succeed every time you run it, for valid reasons...

Sure Celery has API for it. Here is an example how to do it from a script: `res = app.control.revoke(task_id, terminate=True)`

In the example above `app` is an instance of the Celery application.

In some rare ocasions the control command above will not work, in which case you have to instruct Celery worker to kill the worker process: `res = app.control.revoke(task_id, terminate=True, signal='SIGKILL')`

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem so for future readers,

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#i-ve-purged-messages-but-there-are-still-messages-left-in-the-queue

> so to properly purge the queue of waiting tasks you have to **stop all
>   the workers**, and then purge the tasks using celery.control.purge().

Comment: Again, like the accepted "answer" - this one is incorrect too. The question is how to revoke particular task, not how to purge the queue...

Answer (score 0):

1.
To properly purge the queue of waiting tasks you have to stop all the workers (http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#i-ve-purged-messages-but-there-are-still-messages-left-in-the-queue):

2 ... and then purge the tasks from a specific queue:

```
$ cd <source_dir
$ celery amqp queue.purge <queue name>
```

3.
Start workers again

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the .state file and if you are using a beat worker (celery worker -B) then remove the schedule file as well

Comment: i removed all of state and scheduled, then deleted the queues and it worked for me